# How to align 2 by 2 divs around a centre? E.g. internal corners should be in parent centre

Tags: html, css

looking for some help with html and css (more with css) I want to make that work as a template to be use with a parent div in my app, but having problems to center 4 divs in a centre of sub parent. I need they align in central point by they inner corners.
E.g. corner of 1st right bottom, 2nd - left bottom, 3rd - right top, 4th - left top should be centered.

1-2-3-4 div size may vary

```
I have this https://codepen.io/Kvark/pen/zYzEgWo (updated) to explain:
```

But don't know how to make cantering stuff I need,
now its look like as that: [image]
But I want it to be look like as that: [image]

any advice or help on that?

Comment: Your codepen result and your picture look the same to me. Can you explain a bit more what the final result should look like? Do you want the 4 corners that you mention all to be in the same place?

Comment: red line is where i want them actually to be - top should move to red line, and bottom move up to meet them in centre

Comment: updated pen and question to make its more clear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can position each of the squares within the right hand box by making the right hand box have a position (I've given it relative) and the colored boxes positioned in relation to that.

As the boxes have differing dimensions, which may not be overtly known at run time, this snippet uses a translation of each to get them in the right positions as a translate with a % uses the relevant dimension of the item itself (not its parent) if you use % units.

```css
html,
body,
{
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

div .item {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  border: 2px dashed #f69c55;
}

#container {
  height: 50%;
}

.column {
  float: left;
  padding: 10px;
  height: 300px;
}

.left {
  width: 50%;
}

.right {
  width: 45%;
}

.column.right.square {
  position: relative;
}

#chart_1 {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
}

#chart_2 {
  height: 60px;
  width: 60px;
}

#chart_3 {
  height: 150px;
  width: 120px;
}

#chart_4 {
  height: 50px;
  width: 180px;
}

.square {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
}

.square::after {
  content: '';
  width: 100%;
}

.square .item:nth-child(n + 3) {
  order: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="column left" style="background-color:#aaa;">
    <h2>tbd</h2>
    <div id="container"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="column right square" style="background-color:#bbb;">
    <div class="item" id="chart_1" style="background-color:red;position: absolute; left: 50%; top: 50%;transform: translate(-100%, -100%);">1</div>
    <div class="item" id="chart_2" style="background-color:blue;position: absolute; left: 50%; top: 50%;transform: translate(0, -100%);">2</div>
    <div class="item" id="chart_3" style="background-color:green;position: absolute; left: 50%; top: 50%;transform: translate(-100%, 0%);">3</div>
    <div class="item" id="chart_4" style="background-color:yellow;position: absolute; left: 50%; top: 50%;transform: translate(0, 0);">4</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks a lot, that exactly that i need to!

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly you want the boxes to be tightly placed together, and then you want the "box of boxes" to be placed in the middle of their parent?

If so, here is one way to solve it: using an additional wrapping div to group the boxes together, they can then be placed together.

```css
.item {
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  border: 2px dashed #f69c55;
}

/* This puts the boxes in two columns. */
.boxwrapper {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
}

.wrapper {
  background-color: slategray;
  height: 80vh;
  
  /* This puts the boxes in the middle, and restricts the width and height
     of the boxwrapper, so that the boxes end up close together. */
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="boxwrapper">
        <div class="item" style="background-color:tomato;">1</div>
        <div class="item" style="background-color:royalblue;">2</div>
        <div class="item" style="background-color:forestgreen;">3</div>
        <div class="item" style="background-color:gold;">4</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: updated pen and question to make its more clear

Answer (score 0):

You need Grid to make a template here. Try this

```css
.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto auto;
  grid-row-gap: 20px;
  justify-content: center;
}

.item {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  display: grid;
  justify-content: center;
  align-content: center;
  background-color: red;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="item">1</div>
  <div class="item">2</div>
  <div class="item">3</div>
  <div class="item">4</div>
</div>
```

Comment: but they not joined by inner corners?

Comment: remove the `grid-row-gap: 20px;` then they should join

Comment: updated pen and question to make its more clear

Answer (score 0):

Working example:

```css
.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto auto;
  justify-content: center;
}
    
.item {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  display: grid;
  justify-content: center;
  align-content: center;
  background-color: red;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="item">1</div>
  <div class="item">2</div>
  <div class="item">3</div>
  <div class="item">4</div>
</div>
```

Comment: updated pen and question to make its more clear